# contenteditable .html() is encoding

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

```
<span id="span1" contenteditable="true">this span is editable & awesome</span>
```

If I do `$("#span1").html()`, it returns `this span is editable &amp; awesome`.  I'm trying to save the new value of `contenteditable`s in the DB, and I want to save them as-is, not encoded at all.

How can I make it so that `$("#span1").html()` returns `this span is editable & awesome` and not `this span is editable &amp; awesome` ?  Same goes for if I have two spaces, e.g., `this span is editable & awesome  and great` (two spaces before `and` gets converted to `&nbsp;&nbsp;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$('#span1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/html/ you cannot be sure what exactly is returned from `.html()` anyway:

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

In addition, your example code seems to have been encoded by SO ...